# Couldn't find file 'jquery', Sprockets::FileNotFound in StaticPages#home error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am self-studying Michael Hart's guide and am stuck in chapter 7.

When I go to `localhost:3000`, an error message comes up, saying it couldn't find file `jquery` and points to line 7 in `application.html.erb` [file](https://github.com/optinovation/sample_app2/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb).

when I delete the line 7, -> `<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`, localhost runs normal without an error.

My [git repository](https://github.com/optinovation/sample_app2).

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by reverting to

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.1.4'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '4.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I asume you did'nt run 'bundle install' because:

In application.js you require jquery which should usually come with the the gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'

Comment: I did run 'bundle install', but still doesn't work - very strange - everything is as is from the book-

Comment: I removed Gemfile.lock and ran bundle install once again, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I removed Gemfile.lock and ran bundle install once again, and it solved the problem.

Comment: It will be helpful if you had mentioned which Gem made the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by... restarting server! It recollected the libraries and worked like charm.